# Inner join 3 tables with NHibernate Queryover

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to join 3 tables  with NHibernate Queryover
, but I cant get it to work. Any suggestions?

I used this code
http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/20/Linq-to-NHibernate-Tutorial.aspx

NHibernate code

```
namespace SimpleNHibernateClient.ConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadALL();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Make ReadALL()
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var makeQuery = session.QueryOver<Make>()
            .Where(_ => _.Name == _.Name)
            .List()

            foreach (var m in makeQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + m.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: " + m.Description); //Dont Work
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public class Car
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}

public class Make
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Model> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
}
 }


 namespace SimpleNHibernateClient.ConsoleApplication
 {
public class CarMap : ClassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        References(x => x.Make).Column("MakeId");
        References(x => x.Model).Column("ModelId");
        Table("Car");
    }
}

public class MakeMap : ClassMap<Make>
{
    public MakeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Models)
            .KeyColumn("MakeId");
        Table("Make");
    }
}

public class ModelMap : ClassMap<Model>
{
    public ModelMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Make)
            .Column("MakeId");
        Table("Model");
    }
}




namespace SimpleNHibernateClient.ConsoleApplication
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                    InitializeSessionFactory();

                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
        {
            _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                              .ConnectionString(
                                  @"Server=localhost;Database=SimpleNHibernate;Trusted_Connection=True;")

                )
                .Mappings(m =>
                          m.FluentMappings
                              .AddFromAssemblyOf<Car>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
```

}

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM Make INNER JOIN Model ON Make.Id = Model.MakeId 
INNER JOIN Car ON Make.Id = Car.MakeId AND Model.Id = Car.ModelId
```

Comment: The usual way is to define mappings between objects, not try to approximate the SQL JOIN statements at the object level. The ORM exists precisely to map relations to proper SQL statements. What are you trying to do and why do you think you need a `JOIN`? Are you trying to get makes based on a certain model?

Comment: Im a beginner with NHibernate and has before used SQL statements. 
I want to get out both Name and Description(for example and its in another table), if I dont use join, how do I do then?

Comment: ORMs aren't an alternative way of writing SQL statements. You define the entities (**not** the tables) and the mappings from objects to tables, then let the ORM create the proper statements. If you define a `Car` with a `Model` property and the `Model` has a `Make`, the ORM will load all entities and you'll be able to write `myCar=session.Get<Car>(id)` and then `myCar.Model.Make.Name` or `myCar.Name` without explicitly loading anything.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But I not sure how to do it my code. I have updated my code above with all code. Have you any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using a list:

```
 IList<Make> makeQuery = session.QueryOver<Make>()
            .Where(_ => _.Name == _.Name)
            .List()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the cars of one make. If you want all the cars omit the where obviously. This is the same as what the SQL would give you.

```
Car car = null; 
Make make = null;
Model model = null; 
List<Car> cars = 
    session
        .QueryOver<Car>(() => car)
        .JoinAlias(() => car.Make, () => make)
        .JoinAlias(() => car.Model, () => model)
        .Where(() => make.Name == makeName)
        .List<Car>();
```

The question is what you want to do?

If you want to get a Make object instance with all it's Models and Cars then obviously you need to add a List of cars to the Model class (and think about using eager fetching). I would not recommend this. It seems the author of the entity classes, i.e. the domain model, wanted to separate the make/model domain from the domain of physical cars. Which seems good to me. If you want all the cars of a make/model, you should return a list of cars, and the NH query will return only as many make/model object instances as the count of make/model rows in the resultset.

It is not possible to return a make with all its cars while the model class doesn't contain a list of cars :)

If you want to return a custom object, you can use this to create some custom transformation, but I would rather re-think what it is I want to do than do this.

You could look into [projections](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx), they are also useful, and have transformations, but, I think, should not be used to traverse relations not defined in the entities, e.g. model -> cars.

Comment: I want testing how I get out values from all "tables" to learn NHibernate

Comment: This query over, without the where clause, will return all cars with makes and models using your entity model (car, make and model classes). It is the only possible query, given your entity model, which will result in the same sql you specified.